# jQuery Cycle Images Do Not Show Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to use jQuery Cycle plugin. One of the problems I'm having is that after the first image loads, the rest of the images don't show up even though they are there. When I inspect the element, it says the width of the image is 1px and height is 33px. I'm using Wordpress.

I'd appreciate your help.

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
fx: 'fade',
speed: 500,
prev: '.slideshow_prev',
next: '.slideshow_next',
width:'fit'
});
```

This is in my page.php

```
        <ul class="slideshow">

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <li>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="slideshow_image"><img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
```

And CSS

```
ul.slideshow {list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block;}
ul.slideshow li {display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
ul.slideshow li table {width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; border-spacing: 0;}
ul.slideshow li table td {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;}
ul.slideshow li .slideshow_image {display: block; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}
ul.slideshow li .slideshow_image img {max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery Cycle, or Cycle2?

I would suggest simplifying your html/css -- I'm not sure why you have the setup you do. Cycle or Cycle2 are both very smart, and should automatically handle most simple layouts. Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
slideshow {
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    display: block;
}

slideshow img {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a width or height assigned to your slideshow. Cycle will normally work this out for you if your slide elements are images. Your layout is most likely collapsing because cycle is applying position absolute to the unordered list items and the table is set to 100 percent of it's width and height.

It looks as if you are trying to use the table to centre your images both horizontally and vertically. I'd recommend using [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and it's [center plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/center.php). It will make the whole process much easier.

Make sure you include the javascript files for both cycle2 and the center plugin. Then you can use the following html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="image01.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="image01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    centerHorz: true,
    centerVert: true
});
```